# При нажатии вставить HTML коды в textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Мучаюсь уж как 2 дня, подскажите как сделать такое:

Есть картинки(иконки)сверху,  нужно, чтобы при нажатие на любую из них в `textarea` который ниже находиться вставлялись спец коды к примеру `<b></b>`, то есть HTML коды.
мне подсказали что это делается на `jquery`.

Comment: при нажатии на картинки <b></b> добавит в textarea, так?

Comment: возможно, вы имели ввиду BB - коды?

Comment: первый комментарий bemulima верный, мне именно так нужно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используй любой из WYSIWYG-редакторов.
Если по-своему, то можно так:

HTML:

```
<textarea name="" id="qwe" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div class="icon" data-type='b'>b</div>
```

JS:

```
var ta = $('#qwe'),
    ico = $('.icon');

ico.on('click', function(){
    switch ($(this).data('type')){
        case 'b':
            ta.val( ta.val() + '<b></b>' );
            break;
//можно дописать другие кейсы для новых иконок
    }
});
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/bJ966/)

Можно улучшить, чтобы обрамляло выделенный текст.